# 403 Forbidden when trying to access a merged Fusion Table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error when trying to access a merged Fusion Table with the code below. Nor I understand why neither how to resolve this.

Accessing the table that has been merged with another table works like a charme.

The merged table as well as the base tables are publicly downloadable.

Anyone knows what could be wrong?? Is accessing merged tables somehow restricted?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>FÖJ-Einsatzstellen</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
        width: 600px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var map;
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var DEFAULT_ICON_URL = 'http://g.etfv.co/http://www.google.com'

      // EDIT: change this key to your own from the Google APIs Console
      // https://code.google.com/apis/console/
      var apiKey = 'PLACE_YOUR_OWN_KEY_HERE';

      // EDIT: Specify the table with location data and icon URLs
      //var tableID = '1i0mw7f4b06sG14-mAO-zEJI1gekZ8wte_J6w05c'; // Basis-Table
      var tableID = '1eCPADfnXccPMAYh24W-pUEF-eiKSlOD9e0xSKBM'; // ge-merge-te Table

      // Create variables for the columns you need to retrieve from the table
      var latitudeColumn = 'Latitude';
      var iconUrlColumn = 'Farbcodierung für Marker';

      function createMarker (coordinate, url, content) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: coordinate,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(url)
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(coordinate);
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map);
          });
        };

      function fetchData() {
        // Construct a query to get data from the Fusion Table
        var query = 'SELECT '
                    + latitudeColumn + ','
                    + '\'' + iconUrlColumn + '\''
                    + ' FROM '
                    + tableID;
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

        // Construct the URL
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
            url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
            url.push('&key=' + apiKey);
            url.push('&callback=?');

        // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
          $.ajax({
            url: url.join(''),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: onDataFetched,
            error: onError,
            timeout : 7500
          });
      }

      function onError(e) {
        alert(e);
      }

      function onDataFetched(data) {
        if(data.error) {
            var errs = data.error.errors;
            var msg = "";
            for (var i in data.error.errors) {
                msg += 
                parseInt(i, 10)+1 + ". Fehler:" + 
                "\ndomain: " + errs[i].domain +
                "\nmessage: " + errs[i].message +
                "\nreason: " + errs[i].reason + "\n";
            }
            alert(
                "Leider sind Fehler aufgetreten (um genau zu sein: " + data.error.errors.length + " Fehler, Code: " + data.error.code + "):\n" + msg
            );
            return;
        }
        var rows = data['rows'];
        var iconUrl;
        var iconUrl_part1 = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=32x32&chco=';
        var iconUrl_part2 = '&ext=.png';
        var content = "mein content";
        var coordinate;

        // Copy each row of data from the response into variables.
        // Each column is present in the order listed in the query.
        // Starting from 0.
        // EDIT this if you've changed the columns, above.
        for (var i in rows) {
          var geocode = rows[i][0].split(",");
          coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(geocode[0],geocode[1]);

          if (rows[i][1] != '') {   // ensure not empty
            iconUrl = iconUrl_part1 + rows[i][1] + iconUrl_part2;
            createMarker(coordinate, iconUrl, content);
          } else {
            createMarker(coordinate, DEFAULT_ICON_URL, content);
          }
        }
      }

      function initialize() {
        fetchData();  // begin retrieving data from table, and put it on the map

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.537778, 9.041111),
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [one of the base-tables](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1OAy_8nR8-FODoQFIDeMyzOqLhELbrvYFkf7JtcQ) has access set to "private".

Comment: OMG... Thanx @Dr.Molle! Silly me was so sure that all base tables were public...

Comment: BTW It seems that changing the accessibility of the base table to public doesn't affect the "total" accessibility of the merged table (I waited some minutes to be sure to avoid issues with any caching mechanisms).  
Had to create a new merged table.